# Safari extension beforeSearch event

Tags: safari, event-handling, dom-events, safari-extension

I want to get the search text from Safari. There for I wrote a Safari extension with an event (`beforeSearch`). But I don't know how to get the search text. 
the code below isn't working. The console writes "undefined".
I also tried `event.target.url`;

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        safari.application.addEventListener('beforeSearch', handleSearch, true);

        function handleSearch(event) {
            console.log("searchevent");
            var s = event.target.message;
            console.log(s);
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are looking for `event.query`.

```
safari.application.addEventListener('beforeSearch', handleSearch, true);

function handleSearch(event) {
    console.log("searchevent");
    var s = event.query;
    console.log(s);
}
```